# bad value in calculation output

Tags: php, math

The following code outputs "3". I was expecting "1".

```
echo $resultado."\n"; // show 2
$valor = $resultado * ($resultado - 1 / 2);

echo $valor."\n"; // show 3, and should be 1
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the division `1 / 2` takes precedence in the order of operations. So you have really have this expression:

```
$resultado * ($resaltudo - (1 / 2))
```

You should add parenthesis to be:

```
$resultado * (($resaltudo - 1) / 2)
```

to get the answer you want.

Answer (score 1):

No, you're wrong. The / has priority on - and so your line is like:

```
$valor = $resultado * ($resultado - (1 / 2));
```

and that is:

```
$valor = 2 * (2 - 0.5); // and so $valor = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the division operator (`/`) has a higher precedence than the subtraction operator (`-`).

Your expression becomes, in order:

```
1 / 2 = 0.5 // Executed first since it's the highest precedence operation inside ()
$resultado - 0.5 = 1.5 // Still in the ()
$resultado * 1.5 = 3 // Final result
```

To correct your expression, insert parethesis around the subtraction, like this:

```
$resultado * (($resultado - 1) / 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The / takes precedence over + or -
To get 1 as a result you need to use

```
$resultado * (($resultado - 1) / 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `$resultado` in the expression, you get:

```
$valor = 2 * (2 - 1 / 2);

2 - 1 / 2 = 1.5
2 * 1.5 = 3
```

My suggestion is review basic math ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
echo $resultado."\n";
$valor = $resultado * (($resultado - 1) / 2);

echo $valor."\n";
```

You were effectively doing `2 * (2 - (1 / 2)` = `2 * 1.5` = `3`

Answer (score 0):

2*(2-1/2)

The dividing operator has higher order operator precedence than the minus sign, so the computer will calculate it like this:
2*(2-(1/2)) = 2 * 1.5 = 3

Use parentheses liberally.